# Concerned about allergies: can I give my chinchilla rabbit foods or treats?

Tags: diet, allergies, chinchillas

I have read that pine shavings are generally considered safe for animals, but not as safe for chinchillas.
 This [link](http://animals.pawnation.com/kind-wood-shavings-chinchillas-2440.html) says that aspen also isn't good for some chinchillas - "Spruce is an another acceptable wood shaving if you want to stick with wood but aren't using aspen for some reason, such as an allergic response to it in your chinchilla."
Can I give my chinchilla some foods or treats that are labeled for rabbits? I have discovered some foods he likes, but I'm worried about allergies.

So, generally what are chinchillas allergic to? Is giving him rabbit foods going to cause a reaction?